# Badge notifications aren't properly escaping HTML

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, achievements-dialog

Looks like badge notifications aren't properly escaping HTML.

I noticed it on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063860/), where the title is `JQuery Mobile <h1> Titles cut off?`, and I was shocked to see the large text here:

[image]

Comment: The +10 below it looks fine, so you're right about it being just badges

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A new badge display was rolled out and I didn't escape question titles - thanks for finding.

Comment: This problem [seems to apply to bounty notifications](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258201/is-there-an-xss-vulnerability-in-stack-overflow-scriptalertxss-script); could you check it out?

Comment: And migrations, too.

Comment: @minitech thanks; it's been fixed.